# Read `data.table` with row filtering rather than read+subset

Tags: r, data.table

I need to read huge dataset to `data.table`. Actually, I do not need all of the dataset but just rows with specific values in specific column. I can perform it with read+subset process:

```
dt <- read.table(.......)
df_filtered <- subset(dt, Hash == '1AB3F' | Hash == 'DC167' | Hash == 'BCBC5')
```

Is there a way to read just rows meet restrictions on `Hash` column?

Comment: Try `fread` for a faster read of the whole dataset.

Comment: As an aside, `Hash %in% c('1AB3F', 'DC167', 'BCBC5')` is equivalent to your multiple comparisons.

Comment: fread + cat + awk pipeline to grep a specific column would probably do the trick

Answer (score 4):

You can also use a pipe to read a file in through `grep`. For example, to read in all dictionary words that contain an "e":

```
w <- read.table(pipe("grep e /usr/share/dict/words"))
```

Comment: This is a good solution on Linux, Unix, OS X, & BSD platforms, but worth mentioning that it won't work on windows computers.

Comment: `fread` can do that even without the `pipe` call: `fread("grep e /usr/share/dict/words")`

Comment: If dataset is huge, as described in the question, I don't think `read.table` is appropriate. You may get your R session stuck for hours.

Comment: @dww Rtools for windows comes with sed for whatever its worth.